# Positions set using the justify-position attribute don't take effect at all

Tags: html, css, sass

HTML Code (it is JSX which is the same as HTML, but class is replaced with ClassName):

```html
<div className="snavbarcontainer">
            
            <div className="toplefticon">
                <a class="test" href="#"><img src={topleft} alt="Testing Logo" /></a>
            </div>

            <div className="mainIcons">
                <ul className="icons_ul">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={ILookupPupils} alt="Pupil Lookup" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMUsers} alt="Manage Users" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IHand} alt="Coming Soon" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMAdmins} alt="Manage Admins" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDash} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDB} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
```

My (S)CSS:

```css
body {
    //! background-color: red; - DEBUGGING ONLY!
    margin: 0
}

.snavbarcontainer {
    background-color: black;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


.icons_ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    
    li /* Adds property to EACH LI, not the UL itself. */{
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
}

.icons_ul {
    justify-content: center;
}

.toplefticon {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Basically, I want the image with the class "test" at the top of the vertical sidebar - and the icons in the center. However what I have done isn't currently working.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `display: flex;` on `icons_ul` and `toplefticon`?

`flex`, isn't inherited beyond the first child.

```css
body {
    //! background-color: red; - DEBUGGING ONLY!
    margin: 0
}

.snavbarcontainer {
    background-color: black;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


.icons_ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    
    li /* Adds property to EACH LI, not the UL itself. */{
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
}

.icons_ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div className="snavbarcontainer">
            
            <div className="toplefticon">
                <a class="test" href="#"><img src={topleft} alt="Testing Logo" /></a>
            </div>

            <div className="mainIcons">
                <ul class="icons_ul">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={ILookupPupils} alt="Pupil Lookup" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMUsers} alt="Manage Users" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IHand} alt="Coming Soon" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMAdmins} alt="Manage Admins" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDash} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDB} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
```

And for the `toplefticon`, it will be top left by default if your document is made for the English language, because that's the default flow for English documents. So no need for that class.

Remember to rename `class` to `className` before using this code in react. Hope this helps.

Comment: That just does [this](https://i.ibb.co/rcrDZqB/image.png)

Comment: Doesn't actually do what I need it to lol, I want it to look like [this (my figma design)](https://i.ibb.co/zJqD79Q/image.png)

Comment: And you think your question description was actually describing that image or your design?